# Low-priority query in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to assign a lower priority to a query in MySQL similar to the `nice` command on the command-line (in Linux)? If not, are there databases that can do something like that?

Comment: Which problem do you want to solve by that?

Comment: MySQL has got the opposite: _HIGH_PRIORITY gives the SELECT higher priority than a statement that updates a table. You should use this only for queries that are very fast and must be done at once. A SELECT HIGH_PRIORITY query that is issued while the table is locked for reading runs even if there is an update statement waiting for the table to be free. This affects only storage engines that use only table-level locking (such as MyISAM, MEMORY, and MERGE)._ source: manual page of [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the `LOW_PRIORITY` or `HIGH_PRIORITY` in your queries depending on the type of query you execute:

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | HIGH_PRIORITY] INTO ...
SELECT [HIGH_PRIORITY] * FROM ...
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] table ...
```

From the [Mysql 5.7 documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) for the `INSERT` query for instance:

> If you use the LOW_PRIORITY keyword, execution of the INSERT is delayed until no other clients are reading from the table. This includes other clients that began reading while existing clients are reading, and while the INSERT LOW_PRIORITY statement is waiting. It is possible, therefore, for a client that issues an INSERT LOW_PRIORITY statement to wait for a very long time.

But it is also said:

> This affects only storage engines that use only table-level locking (such as MyISAM, MEMORY, and MERGE)

So you won't be able to use this functionnality with `innodb` for instance, unless you want to use [`LOCK_TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-locking.html) and thus reduce its performance.

Comment: I [just read here on the dba stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56379/8378) that a LOW_PRIORITY query may never get run if your DB is always busy running normal or HIGH_PRIORITY queries... so food for thought!

Comment: This answer states you can use LOW_PRIORITY for INSERT, SELECT, and UPDATE. As of MySQL 5.7 at least, this option is not available for SELECT statements. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton Thanks, I corrected my answer. `LOW_PRIORITY` is not possible on `SELECT` queries (and not only in 5.7), [but `HIGH_PRIORITY` is](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)